# compare classification models with t-test (or Wilcoxon)

Tags: classification, model-comparison

I am curious whether the statistical test (parametric/non-parametric) are appropriate tools to compare classification models.

For example, consider a data set with 10 features - 6 essential and 4 optional. I build three models (for the sake of simplicity, consider a linear logistic regression function with two outcome classes: 0 and 1):

1. model I - model with only 6 (essential) feature
2. model II - model with all 10 (essential+optional) features
3. model II - model with 4 (optional) features

I split the data set into train/test sets, train three models on the training set and assess their performance on the test set. Each split results in three metrics (for example, accuracy: `m1`, `m2`, `m3`) for each model respectively.

Then I repeat the process n times (n=1000) where each run corresponds to a random train/test split, but **all models are trained and tested on the same data**. The result is a matrix of size `n x 3`.

**QUESTION**

Is it meaningful to apply (paired) t-test (or non-parametric) to assess whether three models are significantly different? Of course the t-test should be adjusted to the fact that runs are correlated.

**NB**

One can of course use a standard method for models selection (for example, LASSO, or similar), however, I am interested not in 'the best model' selected from 10 features, but rather to compare the aforementioned models.